# How can I use the core link field widget with title and URL in a custom form?

Tags: 8, forms

I want to add a link field to my custom form.

Below is the code that I have been trying to use but no success. So can anyone let me know how to use core link field in a custom form in Drupal8?

The below code works for Drupal7 but not for Drupal8. I have also tried using #type => 'link' in the below code.

```
$form['cta'] = [
  '#type' => 'link_field',
  '#field_name' => 'link_field',
  '#field_parents' => array(),
  '#delta' => 0,  
];
return $form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, both of you have actually redirected me in the right direction.
Below are the actual steps that I took to achieve this:

- Create a link field (field_url) in one of the content types using admin UI.
  and use the below code to use that field widget in your custom form or custom block.

  ```
  $form['#parents'] = [];
  // Create an empty representative entity.
  $node = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node')->create([
    'type' => 'upcoming_webinar',
  ]
  );
  // Get the EntityFormDisplay (i.e. the default Form Display) of this content type.
  $entity_form_display = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('entity_form_display')
    ->load('node.upcoming_webinar.default');
  // Get the body field widget and add it to the form.
  // Returns the widget class.
  if ($widget = $entity_form_display->getRenderer('field_url')) {
    // Returns the FieldItemsList interface.
    $items = $node->get('field_url');
    $items->filterEmptyItems();
    // Builds the widget form and attach it to your form.
    $form['field_url'] = $widget->form($items, $form, $form_state);
    $form['field_url']['#access'] = $items->access('edit');
  }
  ```

Comment: Hmm, as far as I see this is pretty much the same answer as mine.

Answer (score 1):

To make: Custom Custom url field behave similar like as core link widget's url field(that add from backend) : then can add additional attributes: 'element_validate', 'attributes' etc

Code:

```
$form['resource_fieldset']['design_tool_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#title' => $this->t('Design Tool Link'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Select Design Tool Link'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#element_validate' => [
    [
      'Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\LinkWidget',
      'validateUriElement',
    ],
  ],
  '#attributes' => [
    'data-autocomplete-first-character-blacklist' => '/#?',
  ],
  '#process_default_value' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => $design_tool_link ?? : '',
];
```

Note: by adding #element_validate attribute :

- Custom  Url field 'll accept external & internal links as default core link widget's URL field do
- Also validation of core link 'll applied  instead of writing same validation again

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create two seperate form fields to do this in Drupal 8.

You can use `textfield` for the title and `url` for the URL field, like this:

```
$form['cta_title'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('CTA Title'),
];

$form['cta_url'] = [
  '#type' => 'url',
  '#title' => t('CTA Url'),
];

return $form;
```

Another solution is to pull the widget out from an entity display. There is a guide how to do that here, https://www.webomelette.com/how-render-entity-field-widgets-inside-custom-form-drupal-8.

Basically you load the entity display,

```
$entity = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->create(['type' => 'article']);
$form_display = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('entity_form_display')->load('node.article.custom_form_display');
```

And then you pull out the widgets and add them to your form,

```
foreach ($form_display->getComponents() as $name => $component) {
  $widget = $form_display->getRenderer($name);
  if (!$widget) {
    continue;
  }

  $items = $entity->get($name);
  $items->filterEmptyItems();
  $form[$name] = $widget->form($items, $form, $form_state);
  $form[$name]['#access'] = $items->access('edit');
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this possibility. At last I will go with this only if I did not get to make that work.However I want to know if there is any way so that we can use the core link field widget in a custom form that gives us the same widget as we get when we create a link field in a content type created through admin UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a link field attached to any entity like a node bundle, or user or ... then you can use a code like this:

```
// Create an empty representative entity.
$node = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
  ->getStorage('node')->create(['type' => 'article']);

// Get the EntityFormDisplay (i.e. the default Form Display) of this content
// type.
$entity_form_display = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
  ->getStorage('entity_form_display')->load('node.article.default');

// Get the body field widget and add it to the form.
if ($widget = $entity_form_display->getRenderer('body')) { // Returns the widget class.
  $items = $node->get('body'); // Returns the FieldItemsList interface.
  $items->filterEmptyItems();
  $form['body'] = $widget->form($items, $form, $form_state); // Builds the widget form and attach it to your form.
  $form['body']['#access'] = $items->access('edit');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Core's link field actually uses a `'#type' => 'url'` form element as base and if the field is configured to support internal links it switches to `'#type' => 'entity_autocomplete'`. See [/core/modules/link/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/LinkWidget.php L186-203](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.0/core/modules/link/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/LinkWidget.php#L186-203)

So if you just want to be able to select entities go for `'#type' => 'entity_autocomplete'`.

```
$form['cta'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
];
```

And if you want to be able to type external URLs there as well you need to override the element validation yourself. Nonetheless you need to add your own simple `'#type' => 'textfield'` element to pick up a user entered title. Same as the link widget does it.